# Number of differential equations and unknown functions in spherically symmetric black hole solution

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems

In General Relativity, when we are obtaining the Schwarzchild solution, we get from Einstein's equation three differential equations but only two unknown functions [A(r) and B(r)]:

$R_{00}=-\frac{A''}{2B}+\frac{A'}{4B}\left(\frac{A'}{A}+\frac{B'}{B}\right)-\frac{A'}{rB}=0,\\
R_{11}=\frac{A''}{2A}-\frac{A'}{4A}\left(\frac{A'}{A}+\frac{B'}{B}\right)-\frac{B'}{rB}=0,\\
R_{22}=\frac{1}{B}-1+\frac{r}{2B}\left(\frac{A'}{A}-\frac{B'}{B}\right)=0.$

Shouldn't the number of differential equations be equal to the number of unknown functions?

Here A(r) and B(r) are defined as

$ds^2=A(r)dt^2-B(r)dr^2-r^2(d\theta^2+\sin\theta^2d\phi^2).$

Comment: What about $R_{33}$?

Comment: $R_{33}$ is linearly dependent with $R_{22}$ because $R_{33}=\sin\theta^2\,R_{22}$.

Comment: The three differential equations aren't independent. It can be shown that only two are: IIRC, take the derivative of one and you can mess around until you show that one is redundant.

Comment: I am assuming that this is vacuum thus taking the trace of Einstein's equation we are left with $R_{\mu\nu}=0$.

Comment: Einstein's equation for vacuum is: $R^\mu_{\ \nu}-\frac{1}{2}Rg^\mu_{\ \nu}=0$. Contracting $\mu$ with $\nu$ we have $R=0$.

Comment: @Ninpou Ah okay, fair enough - I'm more used to showing the independence of the components of the Einstein tensor, but the same method should also apply here.

Comment: I have solved the Schwarzschild solution in a GR course some time ago. But this question came on my mind now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that there are only two functions, meaning we only need two differential equations. Therefore one must be redundant, which is the case. Showering this can be slightly awkward though.

One trick is to take the derivative of the equations and work with these too. With the Einstein tensor it's a lot easier to do, but of course it can also be done with your differential equations here. I'm not sure there's any foolproof method of approaching this though.

A hand-wavy method is to take the derivative of all three equations (which I'll label $R'_{00}$, $R'_{11}$ and $R'_{22}$). Then if you solve $R'_{11}$ for $A'''(r)$, solve $R'_{22}$ for $B''(r)$ and solve $R_{11}$ for $A''(r)$, you can plug these into $R'_{00}$ and see it vanishes. Perhaps there's a better method here but not one that's obvious to me.

Alternatively, note that you can use just two of the equations to solve for $A(r)$ and $B(r)$ completely, then the third equation is automatically satisfied. Therefore one is made redundant, answering your question. However, when you have field equations that you can't find closed form solutions for, the method above is also useful for verifying the number of independent equations.

Comment: I'd bet if you took $B R_{00} + A R_{11}$ you'd be pretty close to having the expression for $R_{22}$ just looking at the above.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I actually tried this first as it looks the most obvious, but no luck. With $G_{ab}$ that sortve thing works, but with $R_{ab}$ and the metric OP's using (without squared functions) I'm forced to take all these derivatives. Would be happy to see a more elegant way though, but as far as I'm aware it's not usually that straightforward (which is why most people never do it explicitly lol).

Comment: Thanks @Eletie! I will try to manipulate these equations on Mathematica. I think it is the fastest way to show this.